# Como usar uma diretiva para ligar e desligar meu componente?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estou fazendo um zoom de imagem no meu site. Quando alguém clicar na imagem, abri-la-ei com zoom. Se o usuário clicar novamente(em qualquer lugar) irá fechar o zoom e voltar para a página:
Porém estou com algumas dificuldades no *Angular*. Meu componente *HTML* está dessa forma:

```
<div class="show-image-container" 
     ng-click="d.showImage=false" 
     zoom-image="#article-body" 
     ng-show="d.showImage">
  <img src="images/_a7bb697f6519a49033d211be0bd99986b6d82b95.webp">
</div>
```

A váriavel `d.showImage` está no Controller. Quando eu clico em qualquer lugar do zoom eu seto essa vaŕiavel para `false`, e fecho a janela atraves do `ng-show`. Fechar está funcionando, porém não estou conseguindo abrir este zoom. Inicialmente `d.showImage` começa com false. Minhas imagens estão assim no html. (E elas eu não posso mudar, pois são recebidas pelo backend)

```
<img src="images/_faffb625b63d75286c34552a802d0a551a9b9339.webp" 
     data-uid="_bdca5c267711"
     data-md-img="images/_faffb625b63d75286c34552a802d0a551a9b9339.webp" 
     data-hd-img="images/_a7bb697f6519a49033d211be0bd99986b6d82b95.webp"
     width="200"
     height="200">
```

Para adicionar o `click` às imagens fiz uma diretiva:

```js
prisvoApp.directive('zoomImage', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
  'use strict';

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
      function setImages(e) {
        var imgs = $('#article-body img');

        imgs.on('click', function(){
          // O que eu coloco aqui?
        })
      }

      var $container = $(attrs.zoomImage);

      if (attrs.usesPrCompileHtml) {
        $rootScope.$on('compileCompleted', setImages);
      } else {
        $container.bind('DOMSubtreeModified.zoomImage', setImages);
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.d = {
    numThumbsVisible: 0,
    ...
    showImage: false,
 };
```

Essa diretiva está no corpo do *HTML* e é executada uma vez adicionando `click` as minhas imagens, porém não sei o que colocar no click das imagens para mudar a váriavel `d.showImage` para true. Tentei fazer `scope.d.showImage=true`, porém não funciona.

- Posso mudar o primeiro código *HTML*, a diretiva e o Controller mas não a imagem em si.
- Outra coisa a imagem dentro do primeiro codigo está fixa, pois estou testando essa questão de abrir o zoom, mas a ideia final seria que ao clicar na imagem (Segundo codigo) eu mudaria o source de `<img src="images/_a7bb697f6519a49033d211be0bd99986b6d82b95.webp">` para a imagem que cliquei no caso pegaria o atributo da imagem `data-hd-img` e colocaria dentro de `src` do primeiro código. Porém não sei como funciona essa mudança de valores no *Angular*.